# Image resizing method during preprocessing for neural network

Tags: image, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network

I am new to machine learning. I am trying to create an input matrix (X) from a set of images (Stanford dog set of 120 breeds) to train a convolutional neural network. I aim to resize images and turn each image into one row by making each pixel a separate column.

If I directly resize images to a fixed size, the images lose their originality due to squishing or stretching, which is not good (first solution).

I can resize by fixing either width or height and then crop it (all resultant images will be of the same size as 100x100), but critical parts of the image can be cropped (second solution).

I am thinking of another way of doing it, but I am sure. Assume I want 10000 columns per image. Instead of resizing images to 100x100, I will resize the image so that the total pixel count will be around 10000 pixels. So, images of size 50x200, 100x100 and 250x40 will all converted into 10000 columns. For other sizes like 52x198, the first 10000 pixels out of 10296 will be considered (third solution).

The third solution I mentioned above seems to preserve the original shape of the image. However, it may be losing all of this originality while converting into a row since not all images are of the same size. I wonder about your comments on this issue. It will also be great if you can direct me to sources I can learn about the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution 1 (simply resizing the input image) is a common approach. Unless you have a very different aspect ratio from the expected input shape (or your target classes have tight geometric constraints), you can usually still get good performance.

As you mentioned, Solution 2 (cropping your image) has the drawback of potentially excluding a critical part of your image. You can get around that by running the classification on multiple subwindows of the original image (i.e., classify multiple 100 x 100 sub-images by stepping over the input image horizontally and/or vertically at an appropriate stride). Then, you need to decide how to combine your multiple classification results.

Solution 3 will not work because the convolutional network needs to know the image dimensions (otherwise, it wouldn't know which pixels are horizontally and vertically adjacent). So you need to pass an image with explicit dimensions (e.g., 100 x 100) unless the network expects an array that was flattened from assumed dimensions. But if you simply pass an array of 10000 pixel values and the network doesn't know (or can't assume) whether the image was 100 x 100, 50 x 200, or 250 x 40, then the network can't apply the convolutional filters properly.

Solution 1 is clearly the easiest to implement but you need to balance the likely effect of changing the image aspect ratios with the level of effort required for running and combining multiple classifications for each image.

Comment: As a fourth solution, what about resizing image such that resized image fits into a 100x100 resultant resolution and filling gaps with averaged color of the image (or with black which is zero)?

Comment: I suppose that is an option but 100x100 is already a small image to classify. Resizing your image so it doesn't even fill 100x100 pixels seems likely to be throwing away information.

Comment: I agree, I use 100x100 just to give a numeric example. I think this option is also not an efficient way, thank you.